# PostgreSQL function does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I have PostgreSQL 9.2 with Pgrouting extension, but when I want to call a function(pgrouting)
does not work.

Id like to compute the shortest path between two point.

```
SELECT gid, AsText(the_geom) AS the_geom
        FROM shootingstar_sp('geom_way', 281346, 280088, 0.1, 'length', true, true);
```

result:

```
ERROR: function shootingstar_sp(unknown, integer, integer, numeric, unknown, boolean, boolean) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
```

I did it same way with astar_sp_delta(); I got same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you haven't configured your enviroment.

According this http://anitagraser.com/2013/07/06/pgrouting-2-0-for-windows-quick-guide/ you must, after install pgRouting, configure the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgrouting;

SELECT pgr_version();
```

Follow this link: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/2.0-Development-Guidelines-and-Standards

and you'll see:

`shooting_star/       - Shooting star **DEPRECATED** This will likely get removed.`

May help:
http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/src/common/doc/legacy.html

http://m1.archiveorange.com/m/att/pF04x/ArchiveOrange_jp2W2cZpN4YFMAOQon7K8Ex5Z3Aa.pdf

Answer (score 4):

It seems you use pgRouting 1.05 function names with pgRouting 2.0
Please look at the documentation for the correct syntax, for example for [Dijkstra Shortest Path](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/dijkstra/doc/index.html#pgr-dijkstra).

The [workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) might be also useful to get started.

Here is a list of [major changes](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/changelog/2_0.html#changelog-2-0) with pgRouting 2.0. For example it says, that "Shooting Star" algorithm has been removed and was replaced with TRSP.